# C#- Copia auxiliar de un arraylist

Tags: c#

Tengo que hacer una seleccion de cosas es decir yo tengo {"A","B","c"}cuando yo selcciono uno de los elementos este tiene que acomodarse en otro nuevo array que me va mostrando los elemento seleccionados, por ejemplo selecciono "A" y esto seria asi {"B","C"} >>>>>> {"A"}, esto lo logre el problema esta cuando entro de nuevo a la seleccion de elementos para cre una nueva combinacion, mis elementos del primer array no se resetean permacen iguales {"B","C"} la idea es que vuelvan a estar como {"A","B",C"} para dejarme armar cualquier combinacion.

```
Console.Clear();
        ArrayList listatermi2 = listatermi;
        Console.WriteLine("Seleccione las terminales del recorrido, ingrese 0 para finalizar");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("[Lista de Terminales] ");


        for (int cont = 0; cont < listatermi2.Count; cont++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}) {1}",cont+1,listatermi2[cont]);
        }


        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        Console.WriteLine("Seleccione una opcion para armar recorrido");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("[Recorrido Armado]");
        for (int cont = 0; cont < reco.Count; cont++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reco[cont]);
        }

        opcion = Console.ReadLine();
        if (opcion == "0")
        {
            menu();
        }
        reco.Add(listatermi2[int.Parse(opcion) - 1]);
        listatermi2.Remove(listatermi2[int.Parse(opcion)-1]);


        opcion3();
```

// nota existe declarada un array original entonces al entrar  a la opcion que me permite armar combinaciones creo una copia del primer de esta manera cada que entre a la opcion se vuelve a crear una copia del original

```
public static ArrayList listatermi = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando haces `ArrayList listatermi2 = listatermi;` en realidad no estás creando una nueva `ArrayList`, si no que copias la referencia de `listatermi` en `listatermi2`. En ese momento, `listatermi` y `listatermi2` apuntan exactamente a la misma posición en memoria, con lo que cualquier cambio que se haga en una inmediatamente queda reflejado en la otra.

Si lo que quieres es copiar una lista en la otra, debes crear una nueva ArrayList y copiar los elementos de una en la otra,algo asi:

```
ArrayList listatermi2= new ArrayList();
foreach (var item in listatermi)
{
    listatermi2.Add(item);
}
```

También puedes usar el método `Clone`:

```
ArrayList listatermi2=(ArrayList)listatermi.Clone();
```